# Does there exist a covering of a square?

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

Consider a square of length $ S \in \mathbb{N} $ and a given set $ M $ of $ t \in \mathbb{N} $ smaller squares of lengths $ s_1,\ldots,s_t \in \mathbb{N} $. Are there any conditions, so that I can see, whether the square $ S $ can be covered by the set $ M $ of smaller squares? (A rotation of the items is not allowed, they have to be axis-parallel. The covering has to be non-overlapping, i.e. two items of $ M $ are not allowed to share a common interior point of themselves.)

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square)?

Comment: Yes, this is quite near to my imagination (i.e. as regards the non-overlapping and non-rotation condition). But in my case, it is additionally allowed, that the items of $ M $ partially lay outside the square $ S $ as long as they cover at least a certain area of $ S $. Furthermore, the items don't need to be distinct as it is the case in your link.